# How to insert Adsense display ad in flutter web

Tags: flutter, adsense, flutter-web

I created a fixed display ad 320px *60px. How do I insert in flutter web where I want?
This is the code I obtained from adsense:

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- MyAd -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:60px"
     data-ad-client="xxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Or is it possible to make flutter not occupy the bottom 60 pixels of the screen and insert the adsense ad there by manipulating flt-glass-pane somehow?

I'm looking at a way to insert adsense ads to a mobile website built in flutter-web

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to insert ads into the listview in flutter-web as below:
Created an html file adview.html

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:80px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

And then, an IFrameElement to make use of the html:

```
// ignore: avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget adsenseAdsView() {
  // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'adViewType',
      (int viewID) => IFrameElement()
        ..width = '320'
        ..height = '100'
        ..src = 'adview.html'
        ..style.border = 'none');

  return SizedBox(
    height: 100.0,
    width: 320.0,
    child: HtmlElementView(
      viewType: 'adViewType',
    ),
  );
}
```

Then we can add the widget from the function adsenseAdsView() wherever we want. I added it in ListView.

Comment: Did it work? Did you get impressions in your Adsense account?

Comment: Yes it works and am getting impressions in Adsense.

Comment: How long does it take to your flutter web site get approved? Did you have already a lot of traffic in your site?

Comment: How were you able to get your application approved? I obtained a "Valuable Inventory: No content" violation as a response. I guess there crawlers are not able to pick up pure JS applications.

Comment: I have built www.droidbiz.in flutter website. I am not able to get my flutter website approved from AdSense. It is giving  "Valuable Inventory: No content". How you got approved?

Comment: Is it safe to use ads inside iFrame?

Comment: Help please...I've been trying this approach, but I receive the error: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep"....What am I doing wrong? =(

Answer (score 3):

You can add Adsense ad unit In Flutter Web with the help of below widget. It's work perfectly fine.

create widget with any name you like. I'm name **BannerAdUnit**
only replace **div** tag *ad unit id* and script add **Url** as you can see in the below widget inside html *body* tag.

```
import 'dart:html' as html;  
import 'dart:ui' as ui;  
  
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  
  
String viewID = "your-view-id";  
  
class BannerAdUnit extends StatelessWidget {  
  const BannerAdUnit({Key? key}) : super(key: key);  
  
  @override  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(  
  viewID,  
  (int id) => html.IFrameElement()  
  ..style.width = '100%'  
  ..style.height = '100%'  
  ..srcdoc = '''  
        <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html> <head> </head> <body>             
                     <div data-frill-widget="your ad unit id will come here" style="width: 340px; height: 460px;"></div>  
 <script async src="url"></script>           </body>  
 </html>           '''  
  ..style.border = 'none');  
  
  return SizedBox(  
  height: 460,  
  width: 340,  
  child: HtmlElementView(  
  viewType: viewID,  
  ),  
  );  
  }  
}
```

The story is not end here. When you add the above code You will see one beautiful error something like that.

> The name 'platformViewRegistry' is being referenced through the prefix
> 'ui', but it isn't defined in any of the libraries imported using that
> prefix. (Documentation)

How to fix this error? Don't worry I'll show you how to fix this error.

Create new file on the root name it **analysis_options.yaml**
and copy and paste the below code and the error is gone.

```
analyzer:
  errors:
    undefined_prefixed_name: ignore
```

Note: On the debugging mode flutter Web app not show you any ads.
if you want to see ads deploy your Flutter Web App. you will see ads like this.

[image]

If you guys don't want to write these spaghetti code try this package [flutter_ad_manager_web](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ad_manager_web). I created this helpful package for display Adsense ads on Flutter Web.

Comment: I am using this package. But it shows me only a square on my screen. And How to load my unitid for publishing?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new package that can help with this. Hopefully makes the process a little simpler.

https://pub.dev/packages/admanager_web

Example to implement:

```
AdBlock(
 size: AdBlockSize.largeRectangle,
 adUnitId: "/6355419/Travel/Europe",)
```

Comment: But how do we get approval?

Comment: I never came right with approval but never kept trying.

Comment: Do you know how to change adUnitId to your AdSense? İf you can do. Tell us. Please!