# Is there AdMob support for Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Is there AdMob support for Flutter web? All libraries that I found are intended only for Android and IOS

Answer (score 7):

As you can see in the image below, Google Admobe is not supported for the web so you can not use it for flutter web or other web frameworks.

[image: Admobe panel]

On other hand, you can use [adsense](https://www.google.com/adsense/start/) and set your ads for flutter web,
and I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63987672/11311853) solution for using Adsense as HTML(with IFrameElement)

first created an html file adview.html

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:80px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

And then, an IFrameElement to make use of the HTML:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget adsenseAdsView() {
  // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'adViewType',
      (int viewID) => IFrameElement()
        ..width = '320'
        ..height = '100'
        ..src = 'adview.html'
        ..style.border = 'none');

  return SizedBox(
    height: 100.0,
    width: 320.0,
    child: HtmlElementView(
      viewType: 'adViewType',
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Is safe to show ads on iFrame?

Comment: Like this guy is saying, "AdSense can't see any content that is inside an Iframe. That means it would appear to them that you are displaying ads on pages without content."  https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/149874717?hl=en&msgid=149905341

Answer (score 2):

**`firebase_admob`** is now deprecated in favour of **`google_mobile_ads`** and both of them do not support flutter web. However, you can use display ads on websites using Google Adsense.

You can create a blank web page and add ads and embed the flutter app in the HTML page.

Ref:

[Google Adsense](https://www.quicksprout.com/how-to-add-adsense-to-your-website/)

[Embed flutter App in website](https://www.quicksprout.com/how-to-add-adsense-to-your-website/)

Comment: I can't get adsense approval for my flutter website :( it says that there it is a blank website without content (actually its not)

Comment: @trueToastedCode did you find any solution? were you able to place ads on flutter web?